# MySQL statement not finding a row with matching data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

On a recent project I am having issues when matching a password in the database.

The query is as follows:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$encryptedPass'")
```

This outputs

```
SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = 'T-McFarlane' AND password = 'äê1\Y¸c'
```

It can find me with just the user but with the password it cannot. I have echoed out both the database password and the encrypted password provides and they are exactly identical - this is what is in the database but it cannot find the matching row.

My question is that does this password contain any special characters or would there be any other reason that this is failing?

I have tried both utf8_swedish_ci and latin1_swedish_ci for my collation setting in the database.

Comment: Never mind why it doesn't work - this is a very risky way of doing your password authentication and you should stop doing it at once.  (See SQL injection).  Try using prepared statements instead.  I suspect the answer lies with binary encryption.  Use a salted hashing algorithm instead and the problem will go away.

Comment: I'm already using a salted algorithm with blowfish. The issue was as stated by Bermer - I had forgotten to escape the strings.

Comment: *Barmar - sorry, multitasking.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in the string:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$encryptedPass = mysql_real_escape_string($encryptedPass);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$encryptedPass'")
```

However, it would be even better to switch to PDO or mysqli, and use parametrized queries.

Comment: Thanks, haven't started a project in an while.
Though I had forgot something for the escaping the string but it didn't come to mind what the function was called/the process.

Did the job perfectly though.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but mysql_query has been deprecated. You should replace it with the corresponding **mysqli** function. See Andy Lester's comment above or [http://codular.com/php-mysqli](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: That comment should go to the OP. Rewriting an application to use a different API is beyond the scope of answering a question, IMHO.